# LINQ EF copy and paste a record with a difference field

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

i need copy and paste some records of my table with just but change one field.
here is my code:

```
                using (ClearWhiteDBEntities cwContext = new ClearWhiteDBEntities())
            {
                var qlstfld = from lstflds in cwContext.tblListFields
                              where lstflds.listId == theLongSrc
                              select lstflds;

                foreach (var item in qlstfld)
                {
                    tblListField lstFldRow = new tblListField
                    {
                        name = item.name,
                        filterFieldId = item.filterFieldId,
                        listId = theLongDes, //this field must be change in paste
                        continueById = item.continueById,
                        destinationId = item.destinationId,
                        conditionId = item.conditionId,
                        userId = userId,
                        date = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()),
                        time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay,
                        IP = trueIp
                    };
                    cwContext.AddTotblListFields(lstFldRow);
                    cwContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

**but i get this error:**
an error accured white starting a transaction on the provider connection. see the inner exception for details.

what is best solution to copy and paste records but change one field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using change tracking:

```
using (ClearWhiteDBEntities cwContext = new ClearWhiteDBEntities())
{
    var qlstfld = from lstflds in cwContext.tblListFields
                              where lstflds.listId == theLongSrc
                              select lstflds;

    foreach (var item in qlstfld)
    {
        cwContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(item, System.Data.EntityState.Added);
        item.Id = 0;
        item.listId = theLongDes; //this field must be change in paste
    }
    cwContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: no i insert a new record same as other record but with diffrence field, here i need to add a new record.

Comment: i need read some records and clone them with on field diffrence.

Comment: let me check just a momemnt

Comment: thank you Backs, it works, would you direct me to read more about this, i haven't seen this action before. thanks again.

Comment: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.changeobjectstate(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.entitystate(v=vs.110).aspx) will help you, i hope